# Kafka - Does auto commit happens in the background or as part of the poll loop

Tags: apache-kafka

I am aware of kafka consumers , commit offsets etc .. However, the place where there are multiple interpretations about auto commit.

[How does kafka consumer auto commit work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546489/how-does-kafka-consumer-auto-commit-work)
[Need clarification about Kafka auto commit and auto.commit.interval.ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230862/need-clarification-about-kafka-auto-commit-and-auto-commit-interval-ms)

From https://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html?page=2,

> Auto commits: You can set auto.commit to true and set the
> auto.commit.interval.ms property with a value in milliseconds. Once
> you've enabled this, the Kafka consumer will commit the offset of the
> last message received in response to its poll() call. **The poll() call
> is issued in the background at the set auto.commit.interval.ms.**

The phrase - "**The poll() call is issued in the background at the set auto.commit.interval.ms**" seems contradicting sometimes as it seems not the case. As the autocommit happens **as part of pool loop** and NOT in the background ***exactly*** at auto.commit.interval.ms. Please confirm

1. Does auto commit happens in the background exactly @ auto.commit.interval.ms though pool is not invoked?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same question. I see that 'in the background` stuff pop up in a lot of places which is quite confusing. The best explanation I could find: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#message-handling